# foreach List of tuples

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a static method that I want to loop through in my view using razor, I don't want to send the data as a model, I want to access the static method.

This is my method that reads a CSV file:

```
public static List<Tuple<string, string>> ReadAdGroups()
{
    var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/ad-grupper.csv");
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"))
        .Select(x =>
        {
            var s = x.Split(';');
            if (s.Length != 2)
                return null;

            return new Tuple<string, string>(s[0], s[1]);
        })
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .ToList();
}
```

Now I want to access this data using razor. I added the include:

```
@using Portal.HelpMethods;
```

Then I want to loop through it in my view:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes">
     @foreach (var item in HelpMethods.ReadAdGroups ) {
          @Html(item.Item1)
     }
</ul>
```

It does not work, I get the below error message

> Foreach cannot operate on method group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the brackets calling the method:

```
@foreach (var item in HelpMethods.ReadAdGroups()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget the brackets when calling your method:

```
@foreach (var item in HelpMethods.ReadAdGroups() ) {
          @Html(item.Item1)
     }
```